# BCS and Oracle: bug in connection string?

Tags: bcs, oracle

I am trying to connect from BCS directly to Oracle, but there is an error:

> Keyword not supported: 'connect timeout'.

I think that the connection string formed for Oracle is in an incorrect format for the method:

```
protected virtual string CreateConnectionString(INamedPropertyDictionary lobSystemInstanceProperties){}
```

**Type**: *Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SystemSpecific.Db.DbConnectionManager*

**Assembly**: *Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0*.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Are there any solutions?

Comment: how did you setup your BCS definition?

Comment: <Property Name="AuthenticationMode" Type="System.String">RdbCredentials</Property> 
<Property Name="DatabaseAccessProvider" Type="System.String">Oracle</Property> 
<Property Name="RdbConnection Data Source" Type="System.String">oracleds</Property> 
<Property Name="SsoApplicationId" Type="System.String">OracleDb</Property>
and thats all about connection,  I don't specify "connect timeout" manually

Comment: Did you successfully setup a SSO application called SsoApplicationId?

Comment: Yes, of course, but the problem isn't in the SSS

Answer (score 2):

Unlike other .NET Framework data providers (SQL Server, OLE DB, and ODBC), System.Data.OracleClient's OracleConnection does not support  Connection Timeout property.
If you remove it from your connection string, it should work.

Comment: Connection string generates at runtime into method above and this parameter hardcoded into. I dont specify "connect timeout" own.